# HMVC Codeigniter Cron Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron

I am trying to add a controller in cron but it is not working and the default controller(For example, Welcome) is loading every time. I don't want to use `curl` or `wget` as both are working but both thows `500 Internal Server Error` while running cron script.

I have tried command for cron,

```
php /home/username/public_html/index.php myfolder/controller method
```

But it always run default controller.

Answer (score 1):

Just set cron URL as follows:
www.domain.com/controller/method/argument

use method & argument in url only if required.

Comment: Please read my question `I don't want to use curl or wget as both are working but both thows 500 Internal Server Error while running cron script.`

Answer (score 1):

After a long search, hit and try I found a solution and worked for me, below is the command which is working,

```
php5 /home/username/public_html/index.php myfolder/controller method
```

One more solution I found somewhere,

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/username/public_html/index.php myfolder/controller method
```

I don't know why but `php5` and `/usr/local/bin/php` instead of `php` work as expected or may be just using `php` will executing older version of php.